# Google input tool not working with flutter textfield widget in windows application

Tags: flutter

Developing app for windows based, in which I want to use google input tool in text field to enter Hindi language text. but it not working properly when typing through hindi in google input tool

work Text field by google input in flutter windows application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.